# How to use weight for android:layout_marginLeft attribute android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have the below code for navigation drawer and i am using the attribute
android:layout_marginLeft="620dp" to specify how much space(width) the drawer will occupy when the drawer layout is opened.
instead of hardcoding fixed width  620dp i want to specify like weight or is there any similar approach like weight for this attribute??

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="620dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

        </ExpandableListView>


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the respective Activity/Fragment of the layout you can find the NavigationView by id:

```
dummyNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
```

and then you can access and change all properties associated to it, including layout_width and height  ;)

Comment: Thanku for replay...but this is not the solution for my question

Answer (score 0):

```
Apply similar to this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```